# How to bring an app developed on Hyperledger Composer to production?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm at the stage of my project where I've

- Developed the Chaincode (Model,Script,ACL,Queries)
- Deployed on IBM Cloud
- Developed Front-end Apps to communicate with the cloud based REST Server
- Tested the code and business logic through Playground and single user REST server

Now I have to add identities, connection-profiles, & business network cards to the mix to make a production-testing ready prototype and to run REST Server on Multi-User Mode. But I'm having trouble with the said things as I can't figure out where and how to implement them. I have gone through the docs and I know that a business network card contains identity, connection-profile, and some metadata, but how exactly does the whole thing work is still confusing me.

In addition to this, is there anything else that needs to be taken care of or added to the solution to make it production-testing ready?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggest to read the resources (URLs) provided here firstly to get some insights -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--node-js-application-development-questions-eg-build-real-time-apps-login-etc

secondly, there are some Composer sample applications you can take a look at to understand some of the issues you're asking about (and obviously - try them out!) -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-applications/tree/master/packages eg Letter of Credit.

Finally, another example you can check out this example use case (Loyalty program, including member registration etc (eg user registration etc etc)) is here -> https://github.com/IBM/customer-loyalty-program/blob/master/web-app/app.js and the 'util' elements such as Identity registration etc https://github.com/IBM/customer-loyalty-program/blob/master/web-app/network/network.js