# Want to create a app using hyperledger Febric for multiple registred users

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Want to create a app using hyperledger Febric for multiple registred users, Also user can manage own data, transfer asset.

I also want to authenticate users based on login token given by back end of our app to the blockchain.

Any idea how can i do this ?

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release/balance-transfer refer this example..

Answer (score 0):

its a broad question, but you can get some insights into your use case below.

First, see resources here  - https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#node-app and here -> [How to bring an app developed on Hyperledger Composer to production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651728/how-to-bring-an-app-developed-on-hyperledger-composer-to-production) plus Composer identity / card programmatic generation (eg identity isue etc) example here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#cardapis

see also this Stack Overflow for links on existing samples that can give you some insights ->  [How to bring an app developed on Hyperledger Composer to production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651728/how-to-bring-an-app-developed-on-hyperledger-composer-to-production/50679601#50679601)

On Authentication of users based on token - see overview of REST server authentication here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html and check out these two token-based auth tutorials -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest and https://www.codementor.io/gangachris125/passport-jwt-authentication-for-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-jqfgkoljn